# string copy routine does not work in C

Tags: c, string

I tried the below code to copy a string in C but I am not getting the correct result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char *string1;
    char *string2 = "abcdefghijk";
    char *ptr = string2;
    unsigned int no_of_chars =0;

    while(*ptr++ !='\0'){
        no_of_chars++;
    }

    string1 = malloc(sizeof(char)*(no_of_chars+1));
    while(*string1++ = *string2++);
    printf("string2=%s\n",string2);
    printf("string1=%s\n",string1);

    return 0;  
}
```

I am getting the below result using the MinGW compiler:

```
string2=string2=%s
```

### string1=ï‼

edit : Okay Changed the code and below code works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    char *string1;
    char *string2 = "abcdefghijk";
    char *ptr = string2, *ptrsrc = string2;
    unsigned int no_of_chars = 0;

    while(*ptr++ !='\0'){
        no_of_chars++;
    }

    char *ptrdst = string1 = malloc(sizeof(char)*(no_of_chars+1));

    while(*ptrdst++ = *ptrsrc++);

    printf("string2=%s\n",string2);
    printf("string1=%s\n",string1);

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: @DYZ I am getting string2=string2=%s

string1=ï‼

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running `while(*string1++ = *string2++);` `string1` points just after the end of the first string and `string2` points to the end of the second string.

That is, they both point at the next byte after their respective null terminators, so `printf` sees two garbage strings (which may be blank).

You could use a different variable to hold the start and current position in the strings, such as:

```
char *pstr1 = string1;
char *pstr2 = string2;
while(*pstr1++ = *pstr2++);
```

Now `pstr1` and `pstr2` point to one character past the ends of their strings, but `string1` and `string2` still point to the start.